# AHK script to click a specific button in a program not working inside the program window?

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a hotkey for a software button inside a program since the devs of the program did not do so.

Here is what I tried to move the mouse, click the button and move the mouse back to the original position:

```
F3::
CoordMode, ToolTip, Screen
MouseGetPos, X, Y
Click 512, 516
MouseMove, %X%, %Y%
Return
```

This works, on say the desktop, but when the program window is active, nothing happens. Is there some way to make this work inside the program window?

Comment: You could ask this question on stackoverflow, it has a larger community, more programming experts than here,  and there is an autohotkeys tag on stackoverflow too. You could also try on the autohotkeys forum https://autohotkey.com/boards/  But do add the answer here if you find one elsewhere.

Comment: Which program are you using this in? Does it run windowed or fullscreen?

Comment: Hi, it runs windowed. It's this scientific tool to clean and analyze physiological data called BPV.

Answer (score 0):

The `CoordMode` command may need to be set for the mouse, not for ToolTip.  Set it for whichever mode your coordinates are relative to (screen, window, client, etc.--see documentation)

You may also want to add an `#IfWinActive` statement to limit scope on the shortcut key binding by making it only work when a window from the desired executable is active, i.e., `#IfWInActive ahk_exe BPV.exe` or whatever your program is.